# Catch exceptions in multi threads and processes program

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, try-catch, inner-exception

I'm trying to catch some specific exception. The problem is that my program is complex and can hide this exception as a 'primary' exception or as an inner exception inside an aggregated exception. (it could also be an inner of an inner exception and so on)
How do I catch this in an elegant way?
What I've done so far

```
            catch (Exception e) when (e.InnerException is MyOwnSpecialErrorException)
            {
                var e1 = e.InnerException as MyOwnSpecialErrorException;
                success = false;
                exception = e1;
            }
```

and also:

```
        catch (MyOwnSpecialErrorException e) 
        {
            success = false;
            exception = e;
        }
```

Of course here I only take care in the case of one nested inner exception, and also this assumes that it is the first inner exception. Can someone think of some way?

Comment: What if the `AggregateException` contains a `MyOwnSpecialErrorException` along with other exceptions? Do you want to ignore the other exceptions in this case?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, I would want to ignore them. One MyOwnSpecialErrorException is enough no matter what other exceptions occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the more concise syntax I can think of, featuring the [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) operator:

```
bool success;
MyOwnSpecialErrorException exception;
try
{
    //...
}
catch (AggregateException aex)
    when (aex.Flatten().InnerExceptions.OfType<MyOwnSpecialErrorException>()
        .FirstOrDefault() is MyOwnSpecialErrorException myEx)
{
    success = false; exception = myEx;
}
catch (MyOwnSpecialErrorException ex)
{
    success = false; exception = ex;
}
catch
{
    success = true; // Ignore all other exceptions
}
```

Comment: why do we need the .Flatten() part instead of access .InnerExceptions?

Comment: @Nika if you know for sure that the `AggregateException` can be at most one level deep, you can get away without the [`Flatten`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.flatten).